# Unable to read input using stdin

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path="";
process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
    var buffer = new Buffer(chunk);
    path = buffer.toString();
});
function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log("Request received" + path);
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(JSON.stringify(items));
    response.end();
});
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

items returning undefined. Any suggestions why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using this code with a quick test, items isn't undefined for me (I get a list of files as intended). Can you try logging `err` in `fs.readdir` and see if something is going wrong there?

Comment: @MrTeddy Why not give us the test and/or put it as an answer?

Comment: Also, is `http` really the way to go just to read `stdin`? I may be confused about how you want to actually interact with this piece of software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter a string `stdin` puts `\n` at the end along with the string. Use the following code to solve this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path="";
process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {      
    var buffer = new Buffer(chunk);
    path = buffer.toString();    
    path = path.replace("\n","");
    path = path.replace("\r","");
});
function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log("Request received", path);    
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
        const opts = {"Content-Type": "text/plain"};
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            response.writeHead(404, opts);
            response.write("path not found");
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, opts);
            response.write(JSON.stringify(items));
        }
        response.end();
    });
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Throws error  : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Narendranath\Desktop\Ass-Node
    at Error (native)
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Narendranath\\Desktop\\Ass-Node\r' }

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget also that `stdin` may be line-oriented (needing a `\n` on the end which will then need stripping off) with an interactive TTY, but may not be with a non-interactive one such as the test I expect @MrTeddy made.

Edit: a non-interactive example:

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');

// Execute the stdin.js test file
const child = execFile('node', ['stdin']);

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});

// Send the path
child.stdin.end("./");
```

stdin.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var path = "";

process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
    var buffer = new Buffer(chunk); 
    path = buffer.toString();
});

function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log("Request received" + path);
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, items) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        response.writeHead(200, {
            "Context-Type": "text/plain"
        });
        response.write(JSON.stringify(items));
        response.end();
    });
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Yes, I used a non-interactive one as well. I wasn't sure how the OP was interacting, didn't think of that as well. For reference this was the test https://pastebin.com/eY2mWtau

Comment: Please edit my answer to add your test text in. Let's not make people follow links to other sites that might delete your work!